# Power BI visual axis - sort axis so that (blank) not in the middle

Tags: sorting, powerbi, null

Anyone know how to rearrange this in Power BI without the blank appearing in the middle? I know I can transform the blanks into something like '0 - No category assigned' but in Tableau you can create a custom sort. Is this possible in Power BI?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the columns in the chart

1. either by category or by value
2. in ascending or descending order

using the ellipsis menu on the upper right corner.

Your visual is currently sorted "by value in ascending order". Change that to sort "by category in ascending order" and the **Blank** category will appear on the first position, or use "descending order" to show it on the last position.

[image]

[image]

You can sort the Category column by another "sorting" column, but naturally this can't include **Blank** categories, because they result from filtering another table that has "unknown" categories.

Comment: Anything unclear with my answer? Did it solve your problem?